# Difference in file size between StringIO and actual File Size

Tags: python, stringio

I have following code

```
import StringIO
import os
output = StringIO.StringIO("c:/temp/file.txt")  
position = output.tell()
output.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
size = output.tell()
output.seek(position, os.SEEK_SET) 
print size
```

It displays size as 22
But when I run following , it displays size as 607011L

```
os.stat("c:/temp/file.txt")).st_size
```

Is there a way to convert 22 from StringIO size to actual size 607011L of file

Comment: Read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) and it'll be *really* clear why this doesn't work (`StringIO` has nothing to do with *paths* or actual *files*). Side-note: Don't learn Python 2. It's a dead language, reaching end of life over a year ago. Learn Python 3 now, and save the effort of relearning it later.

Comment: That displays 16, not 22.

Answer (score 1):

Because `StringIO` does not read the file.  What you have done there is created a fake file that contains that string as its contents.  If you want to read the real file, use `open`.  If you want something that acts like a file but uses a string in memory, use `StringIO`.